# PHP function to check if 2 variables are empty

Tags: php, post, get

I have an index page, I want it to include a page called splash.php and not display.php when a user lands on index.php, but once a user does something (sets a variable) ie if a user searches (variable "query") i want it to include display.php and not include splash.php

What is wrong with this code?

```
function hasGet()
{
    return !empty($_GET['fact']);
    return !empty($_POST['query']);
}

if (hasGet()) {
    include("display.php");
}

else {
    include("splash.php");
}
```

**This question should be removed**

Comment: Will do, but what if i don't get a good answer

Comment: You accept an answer if you think it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two returns as you are doing. Try

```
return (!empty($_GET['fact']) && !empty($_GET['query']));
```

Comment: Nice nickname :) And we've got both answer in on the same second... LOL

Comment: Ty. How come you didn't use parenthesis around your entire return statement?

Comment: the parenthesis are unnecessary.

Comment: @Brendan Long, in this particular case you are correct however I would be for future proofing in case a more complex set of logic is put in to determine a true false rather then putting them in later on.

Answer (score 5):

Only the first return statement is executed. Try:

```
return !empty($_GET['fact']) && !empty($_POST['query']);
```

---

A better way to accomplish what you are trying to do is use sessions.

#### index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['visited'])) {
    $_SESSION['visited'] = true;
    include 'splash.php';
} else {
    include 'display.php';
}

?>
```

This way after a user visits `index.php` for the first time, `$_SESSION['visited']` is set to true and it won't show the splash page throughout their visit.

Comment: @Dasa What does your form/url look like?

Comment: @Dasa That means `$_GET['fact']` is empty, the function returns false, and thus it should include `spash.php`. Is that not happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this...

```
if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "/index.php"){
    include("splash.php");
}else{
    include("display.php");
}
```

2.

```
if(!empty($_GET["fact"]) || !empty($_POST["query"])){
    include("display.php");
}else{
    include("splash.php");
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it works, but second one will probably produce result that you want. Your situation is confusing.